# How to use OnChanges angular in order to change background color?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

In my app I want to change the background color of a specific div when `p2.value` changes from the original value. I am using angular 5

This is my div in the html component:

```
 <div class="col-md-6" *ngFor="let p2 of params | orderBy: 'position'" 
  style="min-height: 96px; max-height: 96px; border-style: solid;
  border-color: #E5E5E5; border-width: 1px"> 
 //do something
</div>
```

I want that when `p2.value` changes, the background of this div has to be #ECF4FD

Answer (score 1):

Try this for color;

```
<div [style.bg-color]="p2.value"> 

</div>
```

and in your css file add like this.

```
.bg-color{
    background-color:#ECF4FD
}
```

Comment: And where I set the background color to #ECF4FD?

Comment: It does not work. I think I have to set somewhere the background color to #ECF4FD

Comment: Please examine [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4veyad). Dont forget generate color property in ts file

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to check whether `p2.value` is changed or not.
Then use this `flag` to add color.

Try like this -

```
<div [style.background-color]="p2.isColorChanged? '#ECF4FD':''"></div>
```

`Or`

In your CSS file

```
.className{
    background-color: '#ECF4FD';
}
```

In your html file

```
<div [class.className]="p2.isColorChanged"></div>
```

Comment: By using this, the background color is always #ECF4FD. What I want is that when p2.value changes from the values taht I get from the db, the backgound changes dynamically from #222222 to #ECF4FD

Comment: You have to valculate this in `.ts` file running a loop over `params`. Make a variable of param as `isColorChanged`. Check it in loop. Then in `html`, check `p2.isColorChanged`. Answer updated